# How to properly remove Mutex?

Tags: c++, pthreads, posix, mutex

Using C++, in one of my destructors, i say

```
mutex = NULL;
```

This however results in an error "`No viable overloaded '='`" in my Xcode.

Same mutex was previously initialized in a constructor as

```
mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
```

Please advise, how can i properly handle this as part of C++ destructor

Comment: You may use `pthread_mutex_destroy()` to destroy the mutex object.

Comment: @Bacchus, that should be an answer so I can upvote it. :)

Comment: @Bachhus please "answer" so i can give you credit

Comment: `mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;` is not an initialisation. Where is the declarator?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use `pthread_mutex_destroy()` to destroy the mutex object.

According to the [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_mutex_destroy.html) specification:

> The pthread_mutex_destroy() function
>   shall destroy the mutex object
>   referenced by mutex; the mutex object
>   becomes, in effect, uninitialized. An
>   implementation may cause
>   pthread_mutex_destroy() to set the
>   object referenced by mutex to an
>   invalid value. A destroyed mutex
>   object can be reinitialized using
>   pthread_mutex_init(); the results of
>   otherwise referencing the object after
>   it has been destroyed are undefined.

Comment: +1. And the reason the original attempt did not work is, of course, that `NULL` is not a `pthread_mutex_t` (and there's no viable conversion).

Answer (score 3):

It is not necessary to use pthread_mutex_destroy on a staticly allocated mutex.  If your mutex is allocated on the stack or heap you should be using pthread_mutex_init and pthread_mutex_destroy.  And most importantly make sure the mutex is unlocked before destruction.

Answer (score 2):

As bacchus said, use `pthread_mutex_destroy()`. If the mutex is a member of a C++ class, I wonder why you initialized it with `PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER`, rather than using `pthread_mutex_init()`, as the macro form is more suited for initialization rather than assignment.